# Why am I getting a 405 response to a DELETE request even though I allow that method in my CORS config?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, cors, http-method

I have a Blazor WebAssembly and C# web API hosted on IIS and
When trying to send a PUT or DELETE request to my API I get this cors error:

[image: Cors error]

While i have this in My Program.cs:

[image: policies]

[image: usecors]

This is the response headers I get back on IIS:

[image: Allowed headers]

This is not right.

because on my localhost when sending PUT or DELETE I get this back, response localhost:

[image: Allowed headers localhost as expected hosted]

localhost works as expected but not IIS.

Why is that?

UPDATE:

there was nothing wrong with my setup as seen above. In my IIS I have to disable WebDav by adding this in my web.config:

```
        <modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
        </modules>
```

And make sure you don't autogenerate your web.config.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: @jub0bs Ok, will keep it mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't conflate

- the methods supported by your resource
- the methods allowed by your resource for CORS.

They're two different things, although the latter typically form a subset of the former. Sure, your CORS configuration allows the `DELETE` method:

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS
```

But allowing a method in your CORS configuration doesn't automatically make the resource support that method! Note the absence of `DELETE` from the [`Allow` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Allow), which lists the set of methods supported by the resource:

```http
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
```

The absence of `DELETE` from this list indicates that your resource currently doesn't support that method. The response status ([`405 Method Not Allowed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)) is another clue.

You need to fix that in your routes or whatever.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I will try to find the solution now. I will update the question when solution is found.

Comment: @JoviSimons Cool. Remember that you can upvote an answer if it helped you. You can accept the answer if it solved your problem and in order to mark your question as resolved.

Comment: unfortunately, I am not allowed to upvote yet.

Comment: @JoviSimons Ah yes. Nevermind.

Comment: Yes question is updated